# android not post anything to URL(no error)

Tags: java, android

I have code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText usernameEditText;
    EditText passwordEditText;
    public Button saveme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        saveme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginn);
        saveme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                    new LoginTask(MainActivity.this,givenUsername, givenPassword).execute();

                    // CALL GetText method to make post method call               
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Context context;

    public LoginTask(Context context, String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://facenegah.com/android/login.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return responseText;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

It's not throwing any errors and is running well with no force close.  However, it's not POSTing anything to the URL, it's even not opening it!

Why is this happening?  Can anyone help me?

Comment: check your server side that how they are catching request parameters...

Comment: im working with php for 5 years .. i checking logs and even that file open its insert query to database even wwhen its not have any _POST or _GET content but this android code not even opening it with data or without data

Comment: 06-22 13:17:02.864    1243-1296/system_process W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client i get this error in console android when i press button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Try:

```
String responseText = convertResponseToString(response , entity);
```

```
private String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response,
        HttpEntity entity) {

    String resp = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        if (response.containsHeader("Content-Encoding")
                && response.getLastHeader("Content-Encoding").toString()
                        .contains("gzip")) {

            GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
            StringBuffer szBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            byte tByte[] = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int iLength = gzip.read(tByte, 0, 1024);
                if (iLength < 0)
                    break;
                szBuffer.append(new String(tByte, 0, iLength));
            }
            resp = szBuffer.toString();
        } else {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
            StringBuffer responseString = new StringBuffer();
            String temp = null;
            while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseString.append(temp);
            }
            resp = responseString.toString();


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return resp;
}
```

Comment: i think you should try this once.

Comment: got its its cuz i write permisson in lowercase :| <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Thats Good you got the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It's because I wrote the permission type in lowercase

It should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: How did this not throw a security exception then?

Comment: i dont know, im using android 5 SDK